# Can whitespace be put into @WebParam name attribute

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Calling my WS I got exception like this:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Found element token but could not find matching RPC/Literal part
```

And I noticed that in my WS there is put a whitespace by mistake:

```
public int clearSession(@WebParam(name = "idCustomer") int idCustomer, @WebParam(name = "token ")String token)
```

But on the other side, consumer has this whitespace as well:

```
@WebMethod
public int clearSession(
        @WebParam(partName = "idCustomer", name = "idCustomer")
        int idCustomer,
        @WebParam(partName = "token ", name = "token ")
        String token_0020
);
```

Is it possible that this whitespace causes this error?

Comment: Is there a chance you could remove the space and make the test?

Comment: Because of some circumstances I can test it tomorrow morning. That's why I tried to asked here to get possible answer earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so today I was able to test it again after removing whitespace and it worked. So it looks like whitespaces cannot be put as `name` attribute but I couldn't find any documentation which says about it. If someone can provide some details what is really happening underneath I would be grateful.